# AWS Event bridge rule pattern to capture event without wildcards use

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I need help in creating a event bridge rule pattern to capture an AWS event given below, with few variables mentioned under angle brackets `<>`, requirement is to capture events where `resources` object `ARN` have suffix of `sample` `AND` prefix of `product`. The solution should not be using wildcards:

Event:

```
 {
      "requestParameters": {
        "bucketName": "mybucket",
        "key": "product/<2023-11-11>/<10-31-04>/<my->sample.json",
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "AWS::S3::Object",
          "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/product/<2023-11-11>/<10-31-04>/<my->sample.json"
        },
        {
          "accountId": "1234567890",
          "type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
          "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
{
  "resources": {
    "ARN": [{
      "wildcard": "arn:aws:s3:::*/product/*/*/*sample.*"
    }]
  }
}
```

In resources array, it will match any ARN that has the matching wildcard. The wildcard expects ARN to:

1. start with `arn:aws:s3:::`
2. can be any bucket
3. the starting folder should be `product`
4. It should have 2 folder
5. the file name should end with `sample`

Sample event of EventBridge

```
{
  "id": "234234",
  "account": "23423423",
  "source": "asdfsf",
  "time": "2016-01-10T01:29:23Z",
  "region": "ap-south-1",
  "detail-type": "234234",
  "requestParameters": {
    "bucketName": "mybucket",
    "key": "product/2023-11-11/10-31-04/my-sample.json"
  },
  "resources": [{
      "type": "AWS::S3::Object",
      "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/product/2023-11-11/10-31-04/my-sample.json"
    },
    {
      "accountId": "1234567890",
      "type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "ARN": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    }
  ]
}
```

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-arrays.html

[Amazon EventBridge: Match an object inside of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708829/amazon-eventbridge-match-an-object-inside-of-an-array)

Comment: i guess thats what my main issue is `resources` is actually an array not object type. Your solutions expects `resources` to be an object/map type, right ?? Will this work ?

Comment: I tried, it doesnt works.

Comment: When its an array, it iterates over each object to match the pattern. In your case, it will try to match the ARN param in each object of your array. I added a sample event. It worked while testing. You can try that in rule creation to test it. If still it does work then can you share the exact event that you are getting for testing? For testing, while creating rule -> Step 2(Build Event Pattern) -> Sample Event (create your own) -> Add your event -> Event pattern (add the pattern) @user1119283

Comment: this solution works. Thanks a lot. BTW a small tip for others who are using wildcards in the event rule, the reason why in my query i mentioned without wildcard was that AWS has out a hard limit of 30 rules only for event rules defined with wild card. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-quota.html

Comment: It's 30 rules per event bus. You can create separate event buses in case you want to handle specific use cases.

Comment: yes, but in our use case we had around 300+ EB rules for similar functionality, so wildcard usage became hard to use.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you please share the link which holds such inner details on how the parsing of event occurs for a given event. I checked the AWS docs they are not have this info .. or atleast i couldnt find it.

Comment: Sure, I took reference from [Array rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-arrays.html) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708829/amazon-eventbridge-match-an-object-inside-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are getting events into the EventBridge, but I set up my S3 bucket to send events. Then I created the following rule and it works as expected:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Access Tier Changed", "Object ACL Updated", "Object Created", "Object Deleted", "Object Restore Completed", "Object Restore Expired", "Object Restore Initiated", "Object Storage Class Changed", "Object Tags Added", "Object Tags Deleted"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["redacted-bucket-name"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{"wildcard": "product/*/*/*sample.*"}]
    }
  }
}
```

The above works for any action, except GET.